TypeScript support with Vue 3 doesn't work
I just wanted to create a Vue 3 app with TypeScript
I did this:
npm create vue@latest

In the following process, I enabled TypeScript and the router. I get a component called HelloWorld, where I replace the <script></script> stuff by this:
  <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    
    export default defineComponent({
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      setup(props) {
        props.message // <-- type: string
      },
      methods : {
        handleClick(x: number){
          console.log("x=" + x); let y= 5; y = "Florian"; console.log("y=" + y);



        }
      }
    })

</script>

In the template, I add these two buttons
 <button @click="handleClick(16)">Click me</button>
    <button @click="handleClick('Amen')">Click me</button>

For the second one, I get no error message, although the argument of handleClick must be a number. Clicking on the second button also works, it prints x=Amen and y="Florian"
I can also create a file in src/utils called test.ts with the following content:
export default function testFunction(): void {
  let y = 5; y = "Florian"; console.log(y); //At least, my idea highlights here an error, saying "Type string is not assignable to type number"
};

Then in the file src/views/HomeVue.vue I can use this function
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <button @click="handleClick">Please click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lg="ts">
import {defineComponent } from "vue";
import testFunction from "./../utils/test.ts";

export default defineComponent({
  mounted(){
       testFunction();
  },
  methods : {
    handleClick(){
      console.log("The button was clicked!");
      testFunction();
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style>
</style>

So pressing the button, prints "Florian". No error, because the types are wrong in the testFunction
Why does the TypeScript support not work?

The question lacks clear problem statement? What does not work mean? That it doesn't check types in a template? It's not supposed to. Use vue-tsc for this as suggested in the docs. The problem is not Vue but your setup. Vue is just UI framework

Have you installed the Vue - official extension in VSCode?

@EstusFlask I can also add this code in the handleClick method, which is not in the template: let y = 5; y = "Florian"; console.log(y); It then prints out "Florian" without any error message.

@BoussadjraBrahim No, would it highlight me the error or what?

@user172501 What are the steps to reproduce? The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Currently there's just broad info that you used npm create vue@latest. It's not enough. There at least two different possibilities, the command asks to use TS or not. There should be a clear and unambiguous way to reproduce. Where do you check for the error? You're supposed to see it in Vite process console during build. Not in dev server, unless you want to slow it down

@EstusFlask I used npm create vue@latest and then I enabled TypeScript and I enabled also the VueRouter.

@user172501 Then type check won't work with npm run dev but will work with npm run build

@EstusFlask Thanks so much! Now the type check works and I could resolve all the syntax erros easily.

Thanks to the comments, I could solve the problem:
I had to run npm run build instead of npm run dev so that the type check would work.
In addition, I had to write
<script lang="ts"> instead of <script lg="ts">
